# Error sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory when I try to upgrade Debian

Tags: linux, debian, apt, upgrade

Error when i try to upgrade Debian based distro

```
After this operation, 347 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
```

if I cancel the process with `ctrl+c` I have the following message:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 received signal 2.
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12758125/6216002 , https://askubuntu.com/q/286467/612676 . Have you looked at these answers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error code is obvious: someone removed your current working directory (the directory from which you started the command).

I recommend to type `cd` to go to your home directory and retry the command.

If someone removed your home directory, chdir to `/` or `/tmp/`.